# How to use this struct method in the struct's new() method?

Tags: rust

If a `description` isn't provided (with `with_description()`), then `description` should fall back to value of `command`. To accomplish that, I created a `description()` method:

```
#[derive(Debug, Default)]
pub struct Keymap {
    pub key: char,
    pub command: String,
    pub description: String,
    pub prompt: Option<String>,
}

impl Keymap {
    pub fn new<S: AsRef<str>>(key: char, command: S) -> Self {
        let description = Self::default().description(); // Get the default description

        Self {
            key,
            command: command.as_ref().to_owned(),
            description,
            ..Default::default()
        }
    }

    pub fn description(self) -> String {
        if self.description.is_empty() {
            self.command
        } else {
            self.description
        }
    }

    pub fn with_prompt<S: AsRef<str>>(mut self, prompt: S) -> Self {
        self.prompt = Some(prompt.as_ref().to_owned());
        self
    }

    pub fn with_description<S: AsRef<str>>(mut self, description: S) -> Self {
        self.description = description.as_ref().to_owned();
        self
    }
}

fn main() {
    let keymap = Keymap::new('a', "echo Hello, World!").with_prompt("Enter your name:");

    println!("{:?}", keymap);
}
```

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=310d1e4d04524735808e3a100036df0d)

I tried to use it in `new()` like this:

```
let description = Self::default().description();

Self {
    // some code
    description,
    // some code
}
```

But `description` isn't falling back to the value of `command`. It's empty instead:

```
description: ""
```

Why is this, and how to fix it?

Comment: You should debug print `KeyMap::default()`, and see what you are assigning to the new instances `description`

Comment: Just curious, if you have the fallback applied when accessing `.description()` from your struct, why does `new()` need to apply the fallback upfront? Can't you just initialize `description` to `String::new()` (or better yet, remove it and let `..Default::default()` do its work) and it'd behave just the same?

Comment: Question look familiar... https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=683108e0e9fd3b6770c16a541d251688 same feeling than your other question, your question don't make much sense.

Comment: @kmdreko Could you post an answer with a code example? I didn't know `description()` would just work without initializing it in `new()`.

Comment: @kmdreko I think you mean something like this? https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=bf463d5ec89dd33a93b84338e00d185b

Comment: I meant something like this: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=96299674cc71c7a70d451c981e59d70a Your code seems *fine* without doing anything with `description` in `new()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `command` of `Self::default()`, a newly created `Keymap`, is the empty string (the default value for a `String`), and so the value returned by `Self::default().description()` is too.